# XSLT 3.0 Intellisense in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, intellisense

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to offer Intellisense based on the XSLT3 schema here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/schema-for-xslt30.xsd ?

I've tried downloading the file and adding it to the schema list ( XML -> Schemas -> Add ) and removing the built-in XSLT version, but it then doesn't seem to offer up any Intellisense.

I have another custom schema that works perfectly when added to the schema list, so VS seems to be providing proper Intellisense and checking of code with multiple schemas, but it seems to hate the official one from W3.org.

Has anyone tried to achieve this with some success before? I've done a fair amount of Googling and reading Stackoverflow questions related to VS2010 and can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema is an XSD version 1.1 schema, Microsoft does only support XSD 1.0. So you would need to try to remove any XSD 1.1 features before you get any chance to use that schema with Microsoft's XSD 1.0 based XML Intellisense.

At https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/xslt.xsd I have an attempt to comment out features from XSD 1.1 like assertions, if you select that file in VS 2019 for XSLT namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` based Intellisense instead of the built-in one VS uses for XSLT 1.0 you should get XSLT 3.0 intellisense; note that I haven't thoroughly tested that, use it at your own convenience but with no warranty.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I was looking for, thank you! The only change I made to it is to remove the attributes which contain underscores because VS then sorts those to the top of the suggestions. Works perfectly.

Comment: @GuyMuntonJackson, the attributes beginning with an underscore are the new feature of so called "shadow" attributes that allow together with static parameters and variables to use attribute value templates at compile-time for e.g. `xsl:template _match="{$my-pattern}"`. It's a powerful and handy feature in some use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Phil Fearon's plug-in?

https://www.xml.com/news/2020-06-xsltxpath-for-vsc-released-vsc-marketplace/

Comment: That is for Visual Studio Code, not for Visual Studio.

Comment: That plugin is excellent for XSLT work (the best I've seen), it just doesn't yet support code completion from other referenced schemas like VS2019 does. In our case, we use both the XSLT and a custom schema for development.